# Would we benefit from having a self-answered question explaining why the "dark side of the moon" terminology is confusing?

Tags: discussion, questions

I notice that it comes up a lot around here and Space Exploration that someone seems to have a misconception regarding the "dark side of the moon". Would it be beneficial to our community to have a self-answered question addressing this to point people to from both Space Exploration and Astronomy?